# Laravel 5.4 subquery in where condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery

I want to write sub query inside where in condition and in subquery were condition, checking with parent query field.

as follows,

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$query->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->select('award_user.user_id')
                    ->from('award_user')
                    ->where('award_user.user_id', 'users.id')
                    ->where('award_user.award_id', $request->award_id);
        });
```

Query is working fine, but

```
 ->where('award_user.user_id', 'users.id')
```

This line, users.id is not taking from parent query. If I enter manually number, then it is working correctly.

What is wrong with my query.. can you please suggest.

Comment: Not problem with award id, but issue with users.id

Comment: you should try your query by adding `->toSql()` to get sql format, and run that manually in phpMyadmin or Mysql Query Browser!

Answer (score 1):

use `whereRaw` rather than `where`

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$query->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->select('award_user.user_id')
                    ->from('award_user')
                    ->whereRaw('award_user.user_id', 'users.id')
                    ->whereRaw('award_user.award_id = '.$request->award_id);
        });
```

Comment: now parent user id is working but the second `whereRaw` not applying

Comment: @NaseehaSahla, `->whereRaw('award_user.award_id = '.$request->award_id);` use this as second `whereRaw` value.

Comment: in second whereRaw is not worling but where is working than dont't change in  second still not working than let me know